# Правильное ударение

Tags: грамотная-речь, фонетика

ВорОтимся или ВоротИмся
ВорОтятся или ВоротЯтся

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ВорОтимся, ворОтятся (источник - «Полная акцентуированная парадигма по А. А. Зализняку»)